# Why doesn't any cryptographic library apply the Lehman's method?

Tags: rsa

Lehman's method can be described as;

Let $N=pq$. If the ration of $p/q$ is near a ratio of two small numbers $r/s$, then $ps$ and $qr$ are close to $\sqrt{nrs}$. The Fermat's method can be easy applied to $nrs$, and $p=\gcd(ps,n)$, $q=n/p$.

Why doesn't any cryptographic library apply the Lehman's method?

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method) Generally, **if the ratio is not known**, various {\displaystyle u/v}u/v values can be tried, and try to factor each resulting Nuv. R. Lehman devised a systematic way to do this, so that Fermat's plus trial division can factor $N$ in $O(N^{1/3})$ time

Comment: The true Lehman's algorithm [here](https://programmingpraxis.com/2017/08/22/lehmans-factoring-algorithm/). Your one missed imporatant details

Answer (score 6):

I think the question really is: why don't cryptographic libraries generating RSA keys check if $p$ and $q$ are such that $N$ would be easily to factorize by Lehman's method?

That's because the probability that this stands are negligible. One way to prove this is to establish that Lehman's method overall has cost $O(N^{1/3})$ for random distribution of $p$ and $q$ with whatever limit the generation method has, like $\max(p,q)<2\min(p,q)$. [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) and [Lentra's ECM factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) are more credible ways to factor such $N$, and the later has to an even higher degree than Lehman's method the characteristic of having probability of success grow progressively with effort. So why bother with a test against Lehman's method when a rational adversary would skip Lehman's method in favor of GNFS or ECM?

Then one can ask: so why do some cryptographic libraries generating RSA keys check if $\lvert p–q\rvert$ is above some bound, apparently to protect against Fermat's factorization method? That's because it's a way to check some failure modes of the prime generator, including returning a constant value. And because $\lvert p–q\rvert>2^{(n_\text{len}/2)–100}$ is mandated by [FIPS 186-4, section B.3.1, item 2(d)](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=62).

But why is there this check in FIPS 186-4? I guess that's essentially because it's been in the earlier ANSI X9.31:1988, combined with it's indirect way of checking some horrible RNG failure, and the unlikeliness that it would harm (even in a side-channel attack).

But why is there this check in ANSI X9.31:1988? My understanding is that's bowing to request of some member(s) of the committee, sponsored by bankers, who wanted to show that every reasonable precaution was taken. Based on my memory of what Bob Silverman (who stood at this committee and was instrumental in writing the standard) has reported, the rationale was to make it harder for a lawyer to repudiate an RSA signature in court, by a wrong but superficially credible argument on the tune of: these "RSA signatures" are not admissible evidence! It was not taken reasonable precautions to make the factorization of the modulus $N$ difficult. Look, even some algorithm known to XVII<sup>th</sup> century mathematician Pierre de Fermat could have been used to forge that "signature" thing opposed to my client!

Answer (score 0):

It’s a nice algorithm, and with careful implementation it can factor N in $O(N^{1/3})$, which is substantially better than the naive $O(N^{1/2})$ trial division. It lets you factor 64 but integers in few milliseconds.

It may be the fastest algorithm that requires no deep mathematics, but it’s complicated and takes quite some effort for a talented amateur to get it right, and to prove you got it right.

It’s nowhere near fast enough to factor large products of primes like they are used in RSA in reasonable time.

Comment: "It may be the fastest algorithm that requires no deep mathematics"; nope, Monte Carlo factorization is even faster - expected time $O(\sqrt{q})$, where $q$ is the smallest prime factor; hence $O(\sqrt[4]{n})$, and it is certainly not deep mathematically.

Comment: I never looked at it! Did now. To factorise arbitrary numbers, you’d have to add a primality checker at some point or it will fail if n is a prime. Fascinating also that it fails for n=4 (but most people would eliminate small factors by hand).